# Spring Boot REST Deployment: do we need TomCat?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, jar, spring-rest

I've seen Spring Boot Rest project that generates WAR then deployed in a tomcat container. I wonder if this is best practice because I've also read that in Spring Boot, the new final executable JAR file contains embedded server solution like Tomcat too?

Now i've seen a related post that talks about Spring Boot supports both ways but none talked about the pros and cons of each.

Can someone point out the best practice for deploying a spring boot rest project?

I'm thinking of dockerizing the JAR containing embedded server but i'm wondering if there's any drawbacks vs deploying WAR to Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

A general best practice ( from [12 Factor App](https://12factor.net/dependencies) ) regarding the application environment and dependencies is "Explicitly declare and isolate dependencies".

> A twelve-factor app never relies on implicit existence of system-wide
>   packages

With that in mind one should gravitate more towards using embedded container as part of explicit dependency instead of a requirement that needs to be fulfilled separately.There are multiple choices for embedded container in the jar artifact (like tomcat, jetty, undertow, netty) and their respective configuration is also extensive, so using these in production environment is recommended ( I have used them a lot). However there might be certain times when you would want to create a war instead, for e.g., a war file will be deployable in any full-fledged EE Application server ( Weblogic, Wildfly etc)  which might be mandated by your environment. With a war, your number of options in terms of app server increases. Personally for me,  spring boot jar with embedded tomcat has been quite effective. With embedded container option what you need is a virtual machine with OS and Java installed and you are good to go.

However there is a special limitation related to JSP as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations) in Spring Boot documentaion which explain a good reason why you might need to package as a `war` but still run as `jar`.

Comment: I'm thinking of dockerizing the jar, but what are the pros and cons vs using tomcat?

Comment: Again you can dockerize with tomcat within the image and without tomcat as well with just he jar with embedded tomcat. It's just one more thing to do when creating the image. If you are already using a tomcat with java image from container registry even then you might need to copy some specific tomcat configuration files from your project to the image. With docker obviously you will be able to create a complete portable environment for your applicaton.